# Open file in intellij editor with command lines

Tags: git, shell, intellij-idea, command-line, git-bash

I am using intellij with a git bash terminal on windows.

I can use vim to read a file, but what I would really like would be a command to open a file diretly in the intellij editor.
I did have a look on the official doc but didn't find anything about that.

Any idea how could I achieve that ?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Working with IntelliJ IDEA Features from Command Line](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/working-with-intellij-idea-features-from-command-line.html):

> **Opening file in the editor**
>
> To open file for editing. In the command line, type the following:
>
> **`<IntelliJ IDEA> <path1> --line <number> <path2>`**
>
> where:
>
> - `<IntelliJ IDEA>` is the platform-specific product launcher
> - `<path1>` is the path to the project that contains the desired file
> - `<number>` is the number of the line, where the caret should rest
> - `<path2>` is the path to the file to be opened